# Logout via Set-Cookie fails

Tags: authentication, cookies, logout

We moved our website a while ago to a new hoster and experience sporadically issues where people cannot logout anymore. Not sure if that has anything to do with the hosting environment or with a code change.

This is the Wireshark log of the relevant bit - all is happening in the same TCP stream.

1. Logout request from the browser (note the authentication cookie):

   ```
   GET /cirrus/logout HTTP/1.1

   Host: subdomain.domain.com

   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0

   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

   Referer: http://subdomain.domain.com/cirrus/CA/Admin/AccountSwitch

   Cookie:  USER.AUTH=AOvDEjH3w6xIxUC0sYNOAQR5BZ7pPmEF0RMxqohERN87Ti03Eqxd7rQC/BveqmaszmFg8QoSonP+Z+mtQQivKpvloFsQYretYKR8ENubj+moUBF479K5e4albKxS9mBEWT5Xy/XCnEyCPqLASGLY09ywkmIilNU1Ox4J3fCtYXHelE/hyzuKe9y3ui5AKEbbGs3sN9q1zYjVjHKKiNIGaHvjJ2zn7ZUs042B82Jc9RHzt0JW8dnnrl3mAkN1lJQogtlG+ynQSCyQD8YzgO8IpOnSXLJLaCMGMQcvSyX4YKJU/9sxgA5r5cZVCkHLsReS3eIJtXoxktMO6nxVZJY6MX1YwuJOgLRQvwBy9FFnQ6ye

   X-LogDigger-CliVer: client-firefox 2.1.5

   X-LogDigger: logme=0&reqid=fda96ee5-2db4-f543-81b5-64bdb022d358&

   Connection: keep-alive
   ```
2. Server response. It clears the cookie value and redirects

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found

   Server: nginx

   Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 14:40:22 GMT

   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

   Content-Length: 124

   Connection: keep-alive

   Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"

   Location: /cirrus

   Set-Cookie: USER.AUTH=; expires=Fri, 22-Jul-2005 14:40:17 GMT; path=/cirrus

   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

   X-UA-Compatible: chrome=IE8



   <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>

   <h2>Object moved to <a href="/cirrus">here</a>.</h2>

   </body></html>
   ```
3. Browser follows the redirection, but with the old cookie value:

   ```
   GET /cirrus HTTP/1.1

   Host: subdomain.domain.com

   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0

   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

   Referer: http://subdomain.domain.com/cirrus/CA/Admin/AccountSwitch

   Cookie: USER.AUTH=AOvDEjH3w6xIxUC0sYNOAQR5BZ7pPmEF0RMxqohERN87Ti03Eqxd7rQC/BveqmaszmFg8QoSonP+Z+mtQQivKpvloFsQYretYKR8ENubj+moUBF479K5e4albKxS9mBEWT5Xy/XCnEyCPqLASGLY09ywkmIilNU1Ox4J3fCtYXHelE/hyzuKe9y3ui5AKEbbGs3sN9q1zYjVjHKKiNIGaHvjJ2zn7ZUs042B82Jc9RHzt0JW8dnnrl3mAkN1lJQogtlG+ynQSCyQD8YzgO8IpOnSXLJLaCMGMQcvSyX4YKJU/9sxgA5r5cZVCkHLsReS3eIJtXoxktMO6nxVZJY6MX1YwuJOgLRQvwBy9FFnQ6ye

   X-LogDigger-CliVer: client-firefox 2.1.5

   X-LogDigger: logme=0&reqid=0052e1e1-2306-d64d-a308-20f9fce4702e&

   Connection: keep-alive
   ```

Is there anything obvious missing in the Set-Cookie header which could prevent the browser from deleting the cookie?

To change the value for an existing cookie, the following cookie parameters must match:

- name
- path
- domain

name and path are set explecitely, the domain is not. Could that be the problem?

Edit: As it has been asked why the expiration date is set in the past, a bit more background.
This is using a slight modification of the AppHarbor Security plug-in: https://github.com/appharbor/AppHarbor.Web.Security
The modification is to include the path to the cookie. Please find here the modified logout method:

```
public void SignOut(string path)
    {
        _context.Response.Cookies.Remove(_configuration.CookieName);
        _context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(_configuration.CookieName, "")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-100),
            Path = path
        });
    }
```

The expiration date in the past is done by the AppHarbor plug-in and is common practice. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Wouldn't it be wiser to discard the cookie server-side, rather than client-side?

Comment: it's actually more safe to do so, persisted sessions only expose risk.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess i'd say the historical expiry date is causing the whole Set-Cookie line to be ignored (why set a cookie that expired 8 years ago?).

`expires=Fri, 22-Jul-2005`

Comment: Hi, internally, it is using AppHarbor Securityplugin to do the cookie handling. My guess it follows this guideline: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195(v=vs.100).aspx but also empties the cookie value in case this is not honored

Answer (score 1):

We have had issues with deleting cookies in the past and yes the domain and path must match the domain and path of the cookie you are trying to delete.

Try setting the correct domain and path in the `HttpCookie`.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and excellent notes. I've had this problem recently also.

There is one fail-safe approach to this, beyond what you ought to already be doing:

- Set expiration in the past.
- Set a path *and* domain.
- Put bogus data in the cookie being removed!

`Set-Cookie: USER.AUTH=invalid; expires=Fri, 22-Jul-2005 14:40:17 GMT; path=/cirrus; domain=subdomain.domain.com`

**The fail-safe approach goes like this:**

Add a special string to all cookies, at the end. Unless that string exists, reject the cookie and forcibly reset it. For example, all new cookies must look like this:

`Set-Cookie: USER.AUTH=AOvDEjH3w6xIxUC0sYNOAQR5BZ7pPmEF0RMxqohERN87Ti03Eqxd7rQC/BveqmaszmFg8QoSonP+Z+mtQQivKpvloFsQYretYKR8ENubj+moUBF479K5e4albKxS9mBEWT5Xy/XCnEyCPqLASGLY09ywkmIilNU1Ox4J3fCtYXHelE/hyzuKe9y3ui5AKEbbGs3sN9q1zYjVjHKKiNIGaHvjJ2zn7ZUs042B82Jc9RHzt0JW8dnnrl3mAkN1lJQogtlG+ynQSCyQD8YzgO8IpOnSXLJLaCMGMQcvSyX4YKJU/9sxgA5r5cZVCkHLsReS3eIJtXoxktMO6nxVZJY6MX1YwuJOgLRQvwBy9FFnQ6ye|1386510233; expires=Fri, 22-Jul-2005 14:40:17 GMT; path=/cirrus; domain=subdomain.domain.com`

Notice the change: That extremely long string stored in `USER.AUTH` ends with `|1386510233`, which is the unix epoch of the moment when the cookie was set.

This adds a simple extra step to cookie parsing. Now you need to test for the presence of `|` and to discard the unix epoch unless you care to know when the cookie was set. To make it go faster, you can just check for `string[length-10]==|` rather than parsing the whole string. In the way I do it, I split the string at `|` and check for two values after the split. This bypasses a two-part parsing process, but this aspect is language specific and really just preferential when it comes to your choice of tactic. If you plan to discard the value, just check the specific index where you expect the `|` to be.

In the future if you change hosts again, you can test that unix epoch and reject cookies older than a certain point in time. This at the very most adds two extra processes to your cookie handler: removing the `|unixepoch` and if desired, checking when that time was to reject a cookie if you change hosts again. This adds about `0.001s` to a pageload, or less. That is worth it compared to customer service failures and mass brain damage.

Your new cookie strategy allows you to easily reject all cookies without the `|unixepoch` immediately, because you know they are old cookies. And yes, people might complain about this approach, but it is the only way to truly know the cookie is valid, really. You cannot rely on the client side to provide you valid cookies. And you cannot keep a record of every single cookie out there, unless you want to warehouse a ton of data. If you warehouse every cookie and check it every time, that can add `0.01s` to a pageload versus `0.001s` in this strategy, so the warehousing route is not worth it.

An alternative approach is to use `USER.AUTHENTICATION` rather than `USER.AUTH` as your new cookie value, but that is more invasive perhaps. And you don't gain the benefit of what I said above if/when you change hosts again.

Good luck with your transition. I hope you get this sorted out. Using the strategy above, I was able to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems to be the best solution. I hoped to find out what is wrong in the way the cookie handling is done though - But from what I can see it is down to certain browsers interpreting this differently. Your fail safe approach defo should work.

Comment: I am extremely glad this strategy is helpful to you and you see why my approach has merit. It's not "pretty" necessarily, but it always works!